# Use Exit Code Cleanup When Terminating Code Prematurely

Tags: vba, macros

I am running a macro that can take some time in Excel. There may be times I need to terminate the macro early. Consequently, this causes the macro to not perform it's clean-up functions, for example: `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` since it's set to `False` prior to the `Do...Loop` statement I use. This will cause obvious issues, and I usually wind up adding the `True` statement followed by `End` at the very beginning of the macro just to fix the problem.

Is there any method I can use to enable a post-terminate `GoTo` statement in my code? I understand it might not be when I click `Esc`, but what about a persistent box, similar to a `MsgBox` - but one that doesn't stop the code from running? I can use this box basically as a Cancel button, and this box can stay up for the entire duration of the macro without interrupting the macro's operation. Upon clicking the cancel button in said box, it will immediately stop normal operation and follow my `GoTo` command that will perform the necessary clean up duties.

I have a strong feeling this is not possible, but figured I'd ask those who know VBA the best.

```
Option Explicit

Dim ATC As AccuTermClasses.AccuTerm, A As Session, Sheet As Worksheet

Function RemoveSpaces(MyString As String) As String
    Do Until Right(MyString, 1) <> " "
        MyString = Left(MyString, Len(MyString) - 1)
    Loop
    RemoveSpaces = MyString
End Function

Sub CopyEntireFeeBoard()

    Set ATC = GetObject(, "AtWin32.AccuTerm")
    Set Sheet = Workbooks("2016 FEE BOARD.XLSM").ActiveSheet
    Set A = ATC.ActiveSession

    Dim xlRow As Long, aRow As Integer   'Excel's and AccuTerm's Row #s
    Dim Rate As Single, Name As String, Client As String, Desk As Byte
    xlRow = 2   'Starting row
    aRow = 3

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Do
        Rate = 0
        On Error Resume Next    'Incase Rate is blank
        Rate = A.GetText(47, aRow, 4, 1)
        On Error GoTo 0

        Client = RemoveSpaces(A.GetText(10, aRow, 7, 1))
        If Client = "100AAA" Then Client = ""
        Name = RemoveSpaces(A.GetText(26, aRow, 16, 1))
        Desk = A.GetText(56, aRow, 2, 1)

        Sheet.Cells(xlRow, 1).Value = A.GetText(0, aRow, 8, 1)      'Date
        Sheet.Cells(xlRow, 2).Value = Client                        'Client
        Sheet.Cells(xlRow, 3).Value = A.GetText(18, aRow, 7, 1)     'DNUM
        Sheet.Cells(xlRow, 4).Value = Name                          'Name
        Sheet.Cells(xlRow, 5).Value = A.GetText(43, aRow, 3, 1)     'TC
        If Rate <> 0 Then Sheet.Cells(xlRow, 6).Value = Rate        'Rate
        Sheet.Cells(xlRow, 7).Value = A.GetText(52, aRow, 3, 1)     'STS
        Sheet.Cells(xlRow, 8).Value = Desk                          'DESK
        Sheet.Cells(xlRow, 9).Value = A.GetText(59, aRow, 10, 1)    'AMOUNT
        xlRow = xlRow + 1
        aRow = aRow + 1

        ' Reached the end of host application's page.
        If aRow = 22 Then

            'Will go ahead and refresh Excel at this point
            Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

            aRow = 3 'Reset AccuTerm's Starting Row
            A.Output Chr(13)    'Enter key

            ' Give time for the next screen to refresh
            Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
            Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        End If

    Loop Until A.GetText(26, aRow, 1, 1) = " "

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

    Set ATC = Nothing
    Set Sheet = Nothing
    Set A = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Could you provide more info? How exactly do you terminate the macro early? Where is your long running macro code running? Inside Form, Standard Module, some other Class Module? In general, it should be possible to add some Cancellation request which will 'from outside' request the long running operation to interrupt and run some cleanup code.

Comment: Can you post your code?  Also consider posting your code on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) .

Comment: Yes post the code please. I would suggest, instead of hitting `Esc`, to add some button which will request the code to terminate and which will execute the cleanup procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I revised your code to exit if the `Do Loop` when the <kbd>End</kbd> key is pressed.

In addition the data is collected into an array and written to the worksheet n one operation, after the loop is exited.  In this way, there is no need to toggle Calculations and Screen-Updating.

The built-in VBA function `RTrim` does the samething that `RemoveSpaces` does but is more efficient.

---

```
Private Declare Function GetKeyState Lib "user32" (ByVal nVirtKey As Long) As Long
Const VK_END = &H23

Dim ATC As AccuTermClasses.AccuTerm, A As Session

Sub CopyEntireFeeBoard()

    Set ATC = GetObject(, "AtWin32.AccuTerm")
    Set A = ATC.ActiveSession
    Dim AllData, RowData(1 To 9)

    Dim xlRow As Long, x As Long   'Excel's and AccuTerm's Row #s
    Dim Rate As Single, Name As String, Client As String, Desk As Byte
    aRow = 3
    ReDim AllData(0)

    Do
        ReDim Preserve AllData(x)

        Rate = 0
        On Error Resume Next    'Incase Rate is blank
        Rate = A.GetText(47, aRow, 4, 1)
        On Error GoTo 0

        Client = RTrim(A.GetText(10, aRow, 7, 1))
        If Client = "100AAA" Then Client = ""
        Name = RemoveSpaces(A.GetText(26, aRow, 16, 1))
        Desk = A.GetText(56, aRow, 2, 1)

        RowData(1).Value = A.GetText(0, aRow, 8, 1)       'Date
        RowData(2).Value = Client                        'Client
        RowData(3).Value = A.GetText(18, aRow, 7, 1)     'DNUM
        RowData(4).Value = Name                          'Name
        RowData(5).Value = A.GetText(43, aRow, 3, 1)     'TC
        If Rate <> 0 Then RowData(6).Value = Rate        'Rate
        RowData(7).Value = A.GetText(52, aRow, 3, 1)     'STS
        RowData(8).Value = Desk                          'DESK
        RowData(9).Value = A.GetText(59, aRow, 10, 1)    'AMOUNT

        AllData(x) = RowData
        aRow = aRow + 1

        ' Reached the end of host application's page.
        If aRow = 22 Then

            aRow = 3 'Reset AccuTerm's Starting Row
            A.Output Chr(13)    'Enter key

            ' Give time for the next screen to refresh
            Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")

        End If

        x = x + 1
    Loop Until A.GetText(26, aRow, 1, 1) = " " Or GetKeyState(VK_END)

    'Converts the Array of Arrays into a 2 Dimensional array
    AllData = Transpose(AllData)
    AllData = Transpose(AllData)

    With Workbooks("2016 FEE BOARD.XLSM")
        .Range("A1").Resize(UBound(data, 1) + 1, 9).Value = AllData
    End With

    Set ATC = Nothing
    Set Sheet = Nothing
    Set A = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Add e.g. `UserForm` which will have one button for *execution* of the long running operation and another button for premature *termination*. When you decide to terminate the operation prematurely just click the *cancel* button which sets the bool variable and do-loop will exit.

> User Form code
>   *(add two command buttons named CancelCommandButton and ExecuteCommandButton)*

```
Private Sub CancelCommandButton_Click()
    CancelRequest = True
End Sub

Private Sub ExecuteCommandButton_Click()
    Me.Repaint
    CancelRequest = False
    LongRunningTask
End Sub
```

> Standard Module code

```
Public CancelRequest As Boolean

Public Sub LongRunningTask() ' e.g. like CopyEntireFeeBoard()
    ' ...

    Dim result As Long
    Do
        result = result + 1

        ' ...

        ' At the and of the loop check the bool variable and exit if necessary
        DoEvents
        If CancelRequest Then
            ' Do some cleanup
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop Until result = 100000000 ' A.GetText(26, aRow, 1, 1) = " "

    ' ...
End Sub
```